# Fast formula for $\sum_{i=1}^{n} (i \cdot (i!))$, for arbitrary $n \in \mathbb{N}_1$

Tags: summation, proof-writing

I've been reading How To Prove It second edition by Daniel J. Velleman, and I've encountered an end-of-subsection exercise I can't answer. On page 286, exercise 10 of subsection 6.3 states:

"Find a formula for $\sum_{i=1}^{n} (i \cdot(i!))$ and prove that your formula is correct."

By "formula," it's talking about something similar to $\sum_{i=1}^{n} i = n(n+1)/2$, i.e. a formula with few operations for fast calculations of recursive summations with large $n$.

If I know what the formula is, I can probably figure out the proof by induction for myself, but I can't work out a hypothetical formula that works for the first five values of $n$. Here's the first few values:

$n \qquad \sum_{i=1}^{n} (i \cdot(i!))$

$1 \qquad\, 1$

$2 \qquad\, 5$

$3 \qquad\, 23$

$4 \qquad\, 119$

$5 \qquad\, 719$

Any ideas?

Comment: **Hint:** $i\cdot i!=(i+1)!-i!$

Comment: Write the first few factorials and compare

Comment: How about 2,6,24,120,720?

Comment: Additional reading/hint: [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

Comment: @kingW3 jesus christ, that's an **big** number to formulate a hypothesis. Rather as well check up to Graham's number. You've encouraged me to write some code to see how high an $n$ value can get before the computer gets an overflow error.

Comment: @kingW3 UPDATE: for 64-bit unsigned integers, the biggest value $n$ could be before an overflow error is 20; not even close to 2 624 120 720.

Comment: We misunderstood each other I was thinking do you know the formula for the sequence 2,6,24,120,720. If you're writing code I suggest using python since it supports arbitrary numbers and you can easily compute it for much larger numbers(not that it matters for this now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you are looking for is
$$(n+1)!-1$$
I noticed the following pattern: 
$$n=1: (1+1)!-1=(2)!-1=2-1=1$$
$$n=2: (2+1)!-1=(3)!-1=6-1=5$$
$$\vdots$$
$$n=5: (5+1)!-1=(6)!-1=720-1=719$$
I hope you can complete the proof from here.